# Translating ObjC code to iOS Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
 if (self.advertisingSwitch.on) {
        // All we advertise is our service's UUID
        [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
    }

    else {
        [self.peripheralManager stopAdvertising];
    }
```

I have it translated in Swift as:

```
if self.advertisingSwitch.on {

        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBUUID(string: TRANSFERSERVICEUUID)])

    } else {

        self.peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    }
```

It is giving me the error: "cannot invoke StartAdvertising with argument list of type ([CBUUID])"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if self.advertisingSwitch.on {
    self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]])
} else {
    self.peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
}
```